# How do I call OSGI service from outside OSGI?

Tags: osgi-bundle

I am considering writing the OSGI bundle and will expose this as a OSGI service. Now, I wanted to call this OSGI service from another java module,assuming both OSGI bundle and java module running in same JVM.

Is that possible to call OSGI exposed service from outside OSGI ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please describe more exactly the nature of "another java module" you are talking about? What is it?

Answer (score 1):

`BundleContext` is required to obtain a `ServiceReference` which is required to get a `Service`.

Assuming that the `MyService` is in your classpath and that there is only one implementing service in the OSGi container:

```
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;

[...]

BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(MyService.class).getBundleContext();
ServiceReference<MyService> serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(MyService.class, null);
try {
    MyService myService = bundleContext.getService(serviceReference);
    // do something with myService
} finaly {
    bundleContext.ungetService(serviceReference);
}
```

## Variations

1. The `MyService` is not available in your classpath. That is not a problem as you can use any class which is deployed to the OSGi container for the `FrameworkUtil.getBundle()` method and you can pass a String (FQCN) to the `BundleContext#getServiceReference()` method.
2. There are multiple implementations of the `MyService`. Use an LDAP filter for the second parameter of the `BundleContext#getServiceReference()` or call the `BundleContext#getServiceReferences()` method which will return an array or use the same code and rely on the `ServiceRanking`.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I am getting either classloader problems or import problems.

Comment: Yes, I used it with OSGi 4 and Karaf 4.
You should check for NPEs like the `getBundle()` can return `null` but otherwise it is fine.